# React-Hook Form: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'field')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

My form is a nested one and if I'll only submit one product, there are no errors, But If I'll click `Add More Product` and click the button to `add more colors` this is the error that I'm getting:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'field')
```

This is where it pointed out:

```
<input
  36 |   name={`test[${nestIndex}].nestedArray[${k}].color`}
  37 |   ref={register({ required: true })}
> 38 |   defaultValue={item.field}
     |                     ^
  39 |   style={{ marginRight: "25px" }}
  40 | />
```

and here:

```
return (
  19 |   <div>
> 20 |     {fields.map((item, k) => {
     |            ^
  21 |       return (
  22 |         <div key={item.id} style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
  23 |           <label>{k + 1}</label>
```

Adding more products, and adding more colors will make these errors appear

This is what the form looks like:

[image]

Codesandbox link:  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-nested-arrays-forked-vjwbp?file=/src/index.js

The error is in the `fieldArray.js`:

i

```
mport React from "react";
import { useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";
import NestedArray from "./nestedFieldArray";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";

let renderCount = 0;

export default function Fields({ control, register, setValue, getValues }) {
  const { fields, append, remove, prepends } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "test"
  });

  renderCount++;

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {fields.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={item.id}>
              {/* <select
                ref={register()}
                name={`test[${index}].name`}
                defaultValue={item.name}
              >
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="10">ItemA</option>
                <option value="20">ItemB</option>
              </select> */}
              {/* {index + 1}  to show the qty */}
              <TextField
                name={`test[${index}].nestedArray[${index}].product`}
                inputRef={register({ required: true })}
                defaultValue={item.name}
              />

              <button type="button" onClick={() => remove(index)}>
                Delete
              </button>
              <NestedArray nestIndex={index} {...{ control, register }} />
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>

      <section>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            append({ name: "append" });
          }}
        >
          Add product
        </button>
      </section>

      <span className="counter">Render Count: {renderCount}</span>
    </>
  );
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the couple of things that I have found.

1. in `fieldArray.js` file add `item.product` instead of `item.name`

```
<TextField
   name={`test[${index}].product`}
   inputRef={register({ required: true })}
   defaultValue={item.product}
/>
```

2. in `nestedFieldArray.js` add `refer` and `defaultValue` in `Size` component and remove `field1` from name and add `size`

```
<Size
    name={`test[${nestIndex}].nestedArray[${k}].size`}
    menuItems={menuItems}
    refer={register({ required: true })}
    defaultValue={item.size}
    control={control}
/>
```

3. in `Size.js` file first `import React from 'react';` then add `defautlValue` in props

```
const Size = ({ name, menuItems, defaultValue, control }) => (
   <Controller
       as={
           <Select>
               {menuItems.map(({ value, label }, index) => (
                   <MenuItem key={index} value={value}>
                       {label}
                   </MenuItem>
               ))}
           </Select>
       }
       name={name}
       control={control}
       defaultValue={defaultValue}
       rules={{ required: true }}
       fullWidth
   />
);
```

Answer (score -1):

if you're using joedit 100% working||||      const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, control } = useForm();

```
                                                    <Controller
                                                        control={control}
                                                        defaultValue={""}
                                                        {...register("address_en", { required: true })}
                                                        render={({ field }) => (
                                                            <JoditReact
                                                                config={config}
                                                                value={field.value}
                                                                onChange={field.onChange}
                                                                onBlur={field.onBlur}
                                                                ref={field.ref}
                                                            />
                                                        )}
                                                    />
                                                     {errors.address_en?.type === 'required' && <span className='formError'>Address (en) is required</span>}
```

Comment: This code is not really formatted for readability, is it?